# Does Hyperledger Besu limit the amount of data in a transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, besu, hyperledger

I need to send transactions to a private PoA Ethereum Blockchain. I know by geth source code it is limited to 128 KB:  `txMaxSize = 4 * txSlotSize // 128KB` -> tx_pool.go file: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go.
Do you guys know if Hyperledger Besu does limit the amount of data sent in a transaction?

Thanks

Comment: Except if tx gas > block max gas, I don't think there's another limit for tx size given gas is a consequence of the size, limiting gas is the only necessary limit.